# Scala with AWS Java SDK - compiles locally but not on jenkins

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services

Recently I faced strange issue with code compilation - same code works fine on my dev machine (compiles), but fails on jenkins.

My dev machine config:

- win7 _64
- sun jdk6 _64

Jenkins config:

- ubuntu x86
- sun jdk6 x86 - currently set as JAVA_HOME (openjdk6 installed in system next to sun's)

Both use sbt 0.11.2 and scala 2.9.1

Code causing troubles is AWS Transcoder service related.

```
val result = new CreateJobRequest()    
result.setInput(input.asAWSJobInput)    
result.setOutputs(outputs.map(_.asAWSJobOutput))      
result.setPipelineId(pipelineId)
```

- CreateJobRequest is CreateJobRequest from com.amazonaws.services.elastictranscoder.model package
- asAWSJobInput maps scala class to JobInput from above mentioned package
- asAWSJobOutput maps scala class to CreateJobOutput from above mentioned package
- I also use collection.JavaConversions._ here (conversion to java collection in setOutputs).

This compiles fine locally, and returns on jenkins:

value setOutputs is not a member of com.amazonaws.services.elastictranscoder.model.CreateJobRequest

I've tried few things like calling conversion explicitly or extracting setOutputs param into val. I've also tried to use withOutputs - similar result on jenkins. 
What I've also tried is to use setOutput(CreateJobOutput) which worked just fine on both machines.

It seems like environmental related issue, but I have no idea for now what can cause it. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Arek

Comment: Perhaps you have different versions of amazon artifact locally and remote?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the 1.3.32 version](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@com.amazonaws%24aws-java-sdk@1.3.32@com%24amazonaws%24services%24elastictranscoder%24model%24CreateJobRequest.java) of the source code, `setOutputs` is not a member of `CreateJobRequest`.  However, it is present in the class in the latest version in Maven Central - 1.4.6.

It is highly likely that you are comparing against different versions of the AWS APIs locally and on your Jenkins server.

Comment: In the morning I updated version of AWS sdk from 1.4.5 to 1.4.6 (setOutputs afair was introduced in 1.4.4.1) and made jenkins workspace clean up - only 1.4.6 is downloaded and compilation is still failing

Comment: @akaczynski - I bet that you are *still* using an old version ... somehow!  Are you using Maven / Ivy or are you trying to manage your dependencies by hand?  Is it possible that you have multiple copies of the AWS SDK on your build classpath?

Comment: yes, I'm using Ivy and sbt tells me that only one version (1.4.6) of aws-java-sdk is on classpath

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was issue connected with java - it went fine on newer jdk. @Stephen C thank you for your advices